# NameError: name ' ' is not defined in powershell of python file

Tags: python

while I run a python file this shows name error but the environmental setting is ok and I can see the python version:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6mO.png]

Comment: Are you trying to run a python script? That's not how you run a script. You enter `python <script name>.py` into the shell prompt, not the python interactive session.

Comment: thanks, it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a python script, you should call the python executable and pass the script path as argument. Type this in the powershell:

(assuming the powershell points to the same directory as `shakil.py`, otherwise you should either use `cd` command to go to the script directory, or use relative path like `..\some_other_dir\shakil.py`)

```
python shakil.py
```